# Flutter GridView acting weird (web app), Can someone please explain what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, gridview

I have a `List<Map<String,Widget>>` and one function to remove items from it, and one function to add to it, and both `setState` the console is printing that the item removed is actually correct, but on the interface, it's only the last item is removed, and somehow the widget that is to be removed is still there on the interface.
Here are the two functions:

```
addPage() {
    String i = pageHolder.ins.pages[pageHolder.ins.pages.length - 2].keys.first;
    pageHolder.ins.pages.insert(pageHolder.ins.pages.length - 1, {
      "${int.parse(i) + 1}":
          PageWidget(callback: removePage, index: int.parse(i) + 1)
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

 removePage(String index) {
    print("remove page index recerived: $index");
    var i = (pageHolder.ins.pages)
        .indexWhere((element) => element.keys.first == index);
    print("should be removing at: $i");
    pageHolder.ins.pages.removeAt(i);

    setState(() {});
  }
```

and here is what i get in the console:

```
[{0: PageWidget}, {1: PageWidget}, {2: PageWidget}, {7: PageWidget}, {8: PageWidget}, {9: PageWidget}, {: Adder}]
remove page index recerived: 7
should be removing at: 3
[{0: PageWidget}, {1: PageWidget}, {2: PageWidget}, {8: PageWidget}, {9: PageWidget}, {: Adder}]
```

here is the widget code:

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:teacher_page/classes/pageHolder.dart';

import 'classes/audiostreamer.dart';

class PageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final index;
  final callback;
  const PageWidget({super.key, this.index, this.callback});

  @override
  State<PageWidget> createState() => _PageWidgetState();
}

class _PageWidgetState extends State<PageWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("init state is called again and index is:${widget.index}");
    super.initState();
  }

  bool imageAvailable = false;
  late Uint8List imageBytes;
  late Uint8List AudioBytes;
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  bool audioAvailable = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return pageContainer();
  }

  placeholder() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
      child: const Center(
          child: Text(
        "Pick your image",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      )),
    );
  }

  pageContainer() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 100, right: 30, bottom: 50),
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 3,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              child: imageAvailable ? Image.memory(imageBytes) : placeholder(),
              onTap: () async {
                FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                  type: FileType.custom,
                  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
                );

                if (result != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    imageBytes = result.files[0].bytes!;
                    imageAvailable = true;
                  });

                  // File file = File(result.files.single.path);
                } else {
                  // User canceled the picker
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: audioAvailable
                          ? Colors.purple
                          : Colors.grey, // This is what you need!
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (audioAvailable) {
                        await player.setAudioSource(JABytesSource(AudioBytes));
                        player.play();
                      }
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    label: const Text("Play")),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      FilePickerResult? result =
                          await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                        type: FileType.custom,
                        allowedExtensions: ['mp3', 'wav'],
                      );

                      if (result != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          AudioBytes = result.files[0].bytes!;
                          audioAvailable = true;
                        });

                        // File file = File(result.files.single.path);
                      } else {
                        // User canceled the picker
                      }
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                    label: const Text("Pick an audio file")),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: (widget.index > 2)
                    ? ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          // print("remove is called: ${widget.index}");

                          widget.callback(widget.index.toString());
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        label: Text("${widget.index}"))
                    : null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              print("THe text is:$text");
              print(pageHolder.ins.pages);
              // pageHolder.ins.pages;
            },
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 24),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              labelText: 'Word or the sentence for the picture',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 24, fontFamily: "sans-serif"),
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 191, 116, 204), fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: I checked the widget and passed the index to it too, to place the index on the delete button, and it seems like the widget is going away, but the data(text from textfield, image, audio file) are being passed to the widget that takes its place in the list